# How to implement change in transfer_pin and receive an OTP

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on an application and using Django for the backend. It's a payment platform that requires a `transfer_pin` which can be reset or changed for security reasons by the user. When a user change the transfer_pin, an otp is sent to him/her to confirm he is the owner of the account.

Below is what I have been able to do but I am having this error from Twillo that says: **Unable to create record: The number is unverified.** I will appreciate it if someone can help. I feel I am not doing something right.

```
class TransferPin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    transfer_pin = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(regex="^\d{4}$", message="PIN must be a 4-digit number.")
        ],
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.transfer_pin = make_password(self.transfer_pin)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    #  This method checks if the pin matches the hashed pin in the TransferPin instance.
    def verify_pin(self, pin):
        return check_password(pin, self.transfer_pin)
```

```
class TransferPinChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    transfer_pin = serializers.CharField(max_length=4)
    
    class Meta:
        model = TransferPin
        fields = ['transfer_pin']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        otp = random.randint(100000, 999999)
        # otp_expire = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
        phone_number = self.context['request'].user.phone_number
        user = self.context['request'].user
        try:
            pin = TransferPin.objects.get(user=user)
        except TransferPin.DoesNotExist:
            pin = TransferPin(user=user)

        pin.transfer_pin = validated_data["transfer_pin"]
        pin.save()
        send_otp(phone_number, otp)
        # self.otp = otp  # save the generated OTP to verify later
        return pin
    
    def verify_otp(self, otp):
        if str(otp) == str(self.otp):
            return True
        return False
```

```
class TransferPinChangeAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="This endpoint is responsible for This endpoint is responsible for updating the transfer pin",
        operation_description="This endpoint updates the transaction pin",
        request_body=TransferPinChangeSerializer,
    )
    def put(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = TransferPinChangeSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={"request": request}
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                {"message": "Transfer PIN changed successfully."},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
        else:
            return Response(
                {"error": "Invalid OTP."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

Comment: Take a look at [this bro](https://www.twilio.com/blog/verify-phone-numbers-django-twilio-verify)